# React Array in State Mutating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if there is a conflict in the libraries I'm using but for some reason or its, the latest react but when I'm updating an array from the state, it's mutating it even though I haven't called setState. Is there a special case for Arrays in the state that I'm not aware of?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: 'hello' },
        { id: 2, name: 'world' },
        { id: 3, name: 'once' }
      ]
    }
}
performUpdate() {
  const { data } = this.state;

  var current_data = data.slice();

  current_data[0].name = 'helloooooo';

  console.log(data)

  // it shows data.id 1 now has name: 'helloooooo'
}
```

Since I made a copy of the array from state, shouldn't the state be updated only if I call

```
this.setState({
  data: current_data
})
```

Comment: The point is that the `current_data` is a reference for the `data`. So, when you update the value of `current_data`, you're actually updating the value of the `data`. Read [this](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I made a copy of the array from state, shouldn't the state be
>   updated only if I call

You made a [shallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) copy. This:

```
  current_data[0].name
```

is same as saying:

```
this.state.data[0].name
```

`this.state.data[0]` and `current_data[0]` point to **same** object, due to shallow copy; even though `slice` returned new array, its elements basically point to same objects as the elements from the original array.

You [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792457/update-one-of-the-objects-in-array-in-an-immutable-way) interested in how to immutably modify one of array elements.

Answer (score 2):

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) performs a *shallow* copy of the array - meaning that only the pointers to the objects contained in the array are copied, not the objects themselves.

This means that after the `slice` you have two arrays pointing at the same objects. Naturally, then, changing an object in one, will change it in the other.

Instead, what you want to do is create a deep clone. You can use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) or something like Lodash to achieve this.