# If I can't mutate a state, how should I update an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, state, immutability, use-effect

If we can't mutate states in React,

How should I do to update the state of an array of objects ?

```
  const [data,setData] = useState(
    [
      {foo:'bar1',bar:'foo1'},
      {foo:'bar2',bar:'foo2'},
      {foo:'bar3',bar:'foo3'},
      {foo:'bar4',bar:'foo4'}
    ]
);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const filterData = data => {
      return data.map(item=>{
        item.new='bluz'
        return item
      })
    }
    const updated = filterData([...data]);

    console.log("OLD DATA",data);
    console.log("NEW DATA",updated);

    setData(updated);

  },[])
```

The console logs two arrays of objects that all have the 'new' property set.

Using the spread operator `[...data]` does not clone the different items.

So:

1. Do you confirm that I can't mutate the state like that, and that I should then deep clone my array ?
2. Is this the way to deep clone it ?

   ```
   const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
   const updated = filterData(clone);
   setData(updated);
   ```

Comment: For deep clone refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: When the code says: `item.new = 'bluz` each element in the array is being added a `new` prop. If the objective is to avoid this & instead only have this `new` prop on the resulting array, `filterData` should be like so: `const filterData = paramData => paramData.map(o => ({...o, o.new: 'bluz'});`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update one of the objects in array, in an immutable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792457/update-one-of-the-objects-in-array-in-an-immutable-way)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is better you first assigned the state's array in a new array, then change your new array, then use setData(new array).

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important

e.g an image from the same reactjs.org:

[image]

Comment: I dont think so, for example with chat app with large paging data, each time load more a paging data, better we do not mutate new object and append new array data to it