# One way binding not working in angular in table

Tags: angular, data-binding, html-table, binding, angular-components

I have html table and I am binding data from an array in that table. I am changing some values in the array but my changes are not getting reflected in the table. The data is not binded properly. How can I solve this issue.

Html code -

```
<tr *ngFor="let process of processToShow; let i = index">
<td>{{ process.processName}}</td>
<td >
  {{ process.processStatus }}
</td>
</tr>
```

I have an array in ts file like:

```
processToShow: Array[any] = [{id: 1, processName:"P1", processStatus:"Running"},
{id: 2 processName:"P2", processStatus:"Not Running"},
{id: 3, processName:"P3", processStatus:"Running"}];
..
    this.processToShow[1].processStatus="Starting.."
```

I want to change the value from view to source but it is not giving correct value in Html table printing the old value only.

Any ways through which I can properly bind values in HTML table from the source.

Comment: Do you use any change detection strategy?

Comment: You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57011090/11303128

Comment: @VinceCyriac no, not yet

Comment: @ĐỗvănThắng sadly that answer did not work for me.. But you understood my problem my table values are not getting updated in view even they show as updated in console

Answer (score 0):

Angular change detection won't trigger if you mutate the objects in the array

```js
this.processToShow[1].processStatus="Starting.."
```

You should use an approach that updates the array in an [immutable manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792457/update-one-of-the-objects-in-array-in-an-immutable-way)

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue with your declaration of array variable
Try updating code as follows

```
processToShow: Array<any> = [
  {id: 1, processName:"P1", processStatus:"Running"},
  {id: 2, processName:"P2", processStatus:"Not Running"},
  {id: 3, processName:"P3", processStatus:"Running"}
];

...

this.processToShow[1].processStatus="Starting.."
```

Comment: I wrote it wrong in que.. I am actually doing this way only.. The actual problem is my table values are not getting updated in view even they show as updated in console when I update the array elements in ts file. They are not binding properly. Thanks for your ans!

Comment: the code which I have written in que is just for understanding the problem... This is my actual code.. https://pastebin.mozilla.org/VFZZJVzV